# Local MongoDB server refuses to start

Tags: mongodb

I've been struggling to start my first MongoDB server for a few hours now and a lot of answers here suggested that I should turn off my firewall. I did that but the issue unfortunately is still present. At first, I thought that `mongod` command was completely fine and the problem occurs when I run the `mongo` command but after looking up some docs, the output I receive in the command prompt when I run `mongod` is nothing like what I see on the Internet, which makes me guess that the problem is not really from the `mongo` command.

Since the output of the console may be too large and unreadable here, I will attach photos of it but if a copyable snippet is required or wanted, I will add one.

**Running the `mongo --version` and `mongod` commands:**

[image: Running the mongo --version and mongod commands]

**Running the `mongo` command:**

[image: Running the mongo command]

Any help and advice is appreciated!

Comment: seems like you stopped mongo on first screen, than you try to connect to stopped server and connection refused. try not to stop mongod  server in first terminal panel

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't stopped anything, and I run the `mongod` command before the `mongo` one. I am using Windows Powershell, so the two commands are run on separate tabs. They can be seen in the second picture. Judging by the output of the `mongod` command, the server indeed shuts down but I don't know why, as I don't run any other command.

Comment: you should create this folder: `C:/data/db`. It's mentioned in the log